# Covering R2 by rectifiable curves and null sets

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

We have a family indexed by $t \in \mathbb R$ of rectifiable Jordan curves $(\gamma_t)$, such that $\bigcup_{t\in \mathbb R}\gamma_t = \mathbb R^2  \setminus \{0\}$. Moreover, the family is monotone, in the sense that $\gamma_t$ is contained in the closure of the bounded connected component of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \gamma_T$, for all $t < T$. But they are not necessarily disjoint.
For each $\gamma_t$, there is a set $E_t$ with $0$ arclength measure on $\gamma_t$ and we know that $E : =\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb R} E_t$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb R^2$.

Can we conclude that $E$ has zero Lebesgue measure?
In the case where $\gamma_t$ are concentric circles centered at $0$, this is just the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.  It is very tempting to believe that it is also true assuming only $\gamma_t$ to be rectifiable...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is false. Look at the article "Fubini Foiled" by Milnor, Math Intelligencer 19, 1997.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very valuable.

Comment: What would be the minimal assumption of the foliation about the dependence on t that would make E zero measure? I think if we have Lipschitz dependence on t then Fubini applies, but anything weaker than Lipschitz? @PabloLessa

Comment: I'm not an expert but as far as I understand it you need the holonomy transformations to be absolutely continuous.   I'm not sure what other conditions guarantee this.  I think a famous result of Anosov's thesis is that stable foliations of C^2 hyperbolic diffeomorphisms satisfy this in spite of being only Hölder continuous.   I would look at "On the ergodicity of partially hyperbolic systems" by Keith Burns and Amie Wilkinson and check out the introduction and references.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information!